# Upgrading PostGIS on Mac

Tags: postgis, installation, macos

I am trying to upgrade `PostGIS` from `3.1.3` to `3.2.1`. It is on `MacOS Monterey`.

Followed the instructions given [here](https://postgis.net/install/)

1. run on terminal

> ```
> brew install postgis
> ```

2. On pgadmin

> ```
> ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE;
> ```

```
NOTICE:  version "3.1.3" of extension "postgis" is already installed
```

> SELECT postgis_extensions_upgrade();

```
"Upgrade completed, run SELECT postgis_full_version(); for details"
```

> SELECT postgis_full_version()

```
POSTGIS="3.1.3 008d2db" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="140" GEOS="3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2" PROJ="8.0.0" LIBXML="2.9.10" LIBJSON="0.15"
```

Since its not updated to 3.2 I tried:

> ALTER EXTENSION postgis  UPDATE TO '3.2.1'

```
ERROR:  extension "postgis" has no update path from version "3.1.3" to version "3.2.1"
```

However I can see the latest in `/usr/local/Cellar/postgis/3.2.1_4`

How do I set the new path to upgrade PostGIS?

Comment: I know this is a weird suggestion, but try running `SELECT postgis_extensions_upgrade(); SELECT postgis_extensions_upgrade();`  (run it twice)